# How to prompt an input box when an object is detected in real time and have the output printed in a textfile? (Tensorflow Object Detection)

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection-api

I'm using Tensorflow object detection API with OpenCV to detect objects in real-time using webcam.

**NOTE:** I'm using Tensorflow 2.4.1.

How can I display an input box when an object is detected in real-time and then once the user has input his answer, the class name and the user's answer are saved in a text file (.txt)?

For example: once the webcam detects the class 'banana', an input box is prompted asking the user, "How many banana do you want to input?". Then, the user enters 2. In the text file the output will be: banana = 2.

Here's the code for real-time detection for reference:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(ANNOTATION_PATH+'/label_map.pbtxt')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=3,
                min_score_thresh=.9,
                agnostic_mode=False)

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        break
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By directly running this simplified example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import keyboard

#category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(ANNOTATION_PATH+'/label_map.pbtxt')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)

    #input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    #detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    #num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    #detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
    #              for key, value in detections.items()}
    #detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    #detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    #label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    #viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    #            image_np_with_detections,
    #            detections['detection_boxes'],
    #            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
    #            detections['detection_scores'],
    #            max_boxes_to_draw=3,
    #            min_score_thresh=.9,
    #            agnostic_mode=False)

    if np.random.random()<0.05:
        if np.random.random()>0.5:
            detected_item='Banana'
        else:
            detected_item='Carrot'

        print(detected_item + " found!")
        cv2.imshow(detected_item,image_np_with_detections)
        #cv2.moveWindow('object detection',100,50)
        #cv2.moveWindow('something',100+660,50)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        #get the user input:
        user_reaction=keyboard.read_key()
        print(user_reaction)
        #and save it to a text file:
        tiedostonimi="jotain" + str(np.random.randint(10000,20000)) + ".txt"
        tekstitiedosto=open(tiedostonimi,"w")
        teksti="We found" + detected_item + " and ate those " + user_reaction + "...brp!"
        tekstitiedosto.write(teksti)
        tekstitiedosto.close()
        print("...text file saved!")

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        break
```

...you will directly see how every time you get a new detection a new window appears, and the system waits your response, and saves the result in .txt -format. By adopting this example in an appropriate way you find a solution for you problem.

Comment: Hey thank you for replying. After running the code, i'm not able to get the user input message box.

Comment: For advanced user input I'll include another answer, using tkinter-functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

The below-attached stand-alone code shows how to make an "assistant window" to make easily advanced interactive operations or the like with an usual cv2 window. That kind of approach is useful when the basic functionalities of cv2 window are not enough.

To begin "monitoring the cv2 input" simply start the program and you see the "assistant window"...

[image]

...then first press "Start" ...and the cv2 -window apperas, and when a detection is done it looks like that:

[image]

...and when you enter user input (like numbers or text or whatever) and then press "OK", the file is saved like this:

[image]

Next press "Continue search" and the search process for new detections continues.

It is easy to modify the "CV2 assistant-idea" for different kinds of processes alongside with ordinary CV2 image processing.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import keyboard

#let's add some tkinter-functionality for advanced inputs
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#let's make some global variables
global image_np_with_detections
global detected_item
global detection_box_xy
global ikkuna_sijainti
global cv_ikkuna_sijainti
global cap

#initialize the location of the cv image screen...
cv_ikkuna_sijainti=[500,200]

#helpful function...
def change_position(root_variable,x,y):
    root_variable.geometry("+{}+{}".format(x,y))
    root_variable.update()

#let's make a tkinter window...
ikkuna=tkinter.Tk()
ikkuna.title('CV2 assistant window...')
ikkuna_sijainti=[cv_ikkuna_sijainti[0],cv_ikkuna_sijainti[1]-150]
change_position(ikkuna,ikkuna_sijainti[0],ikkuna_sijainti[1])

#category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(ANNOTATION_PATH+'/label_map.pbtxt')

def pollaus():
    global image_np_with_detections
    global detected_item
    global detection_box
    global ikkuna_sijainti
    global cv_ikkuna_sijainti
    global cap

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    painike_1['text']='Search'

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        image_np = np.array(frame)

        #let's ask assistant window to vibrate during search...
        ikkuna_sijainti=[cv_ikkuna_sijainti[0]+np.random.randint(0,10),cv_ikkuna_sijainti[1]-150]
        change_position(ikkuna,ikkuna_sijainti[0],ikkuna_sijainti[1])

        #input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
        #detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

        #num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
        #detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
        #              for key, value in detections.items()}
        #detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

        # detection_classes should be ints.
        #detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

        #label_id_offset = 1
        image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

        #viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        #            image_np_with_detections,
        #            detections['detection_boxes'],
        #            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
        #            detections['detection_scores'],
        #            max_boxes_to_draw=3,
        #            min_score_thresh=.9,
        #            agnostic_mode=False)

        if np.random.random()<0.05:
            if np.random.random()>0.5:
                detected_item='Banana'
            else:
                detected_item='Carrot'

            print(detected_item + " found!")

            detection_box=[np.random.randint(100,200),np.random.randint(100,200),np.random.randint(300,400),np.random.randint(300,400)]
            alkunurkka=(detection_box[0],detection_box[1])
            loppunurkka=(detection_box[2],detection_box[3])
            image_np=cv2.rectangle(image_np,alkunurkka,loppunurkka,(0,255,0),2)
            #paikka=(alkunurkka,loppunurkka)
            vari=(255,0,0)
            fontti=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            fontScale=1
            image_np=cv2.putText(image_np,detected_item,alkunurkka,fontti,fontScale,vari,2,cv2.LINE_AA)

            cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np, (800, 600)))

            painike_1['text']='Continue search'

            cap.release()
            break

        else:
            cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np, (800, 600)))
            cv2.moveWindow('object detection',cv_ikkuna_sijainti[0],cv_ikkuna_sijainti[1])
            cv2.waitKey(1)

    #after while loop let's ask user for the input...
    kysymys()

def kysymys():
    global image_np_with_detections
    global detected_item
    global detection_box
    global ikkuna_sijainti
    global cv_ikkuna_sijainti

    #let's set the assistant window to correct position according to detected item..
    apu_x=cv_ikkuna_sijainti[0]+detection_box[0]-70
    apu_y=cv_ikkuna_sijainti[1]+detection_box[1]-120
    change_position(ikkuna,apu_x,apu_y)

    #and let's put the assistant window on top...
    ikkuna.lift()

def tallennatiedot():
    print("Begin to save a file...")
    user_reaction=syote.get()

    #and save it to a text file:
    tiedostonimi="jotain" + str(np.random.randint(10000,20000)) + ".txt"
    tekstitiedosto=open(tiedostonimi,"w")
    teksti="We found " + detected_item + " and ate those " + user_reaction + " ...brp!"
    tekstitiedosto.write(teksti)
    tekstitiedosto.close()
    print("...text file saved!")


    painike_1['text']='Search'
    return

def lopeta():
    global cap
    cap.release()
    print("Search stopped!")

painike_1=tkinter.Button(ikkuna,text="Start",command=pollaus,height=5,width=20)
painike_1.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10,padx=10)
painike_1.config(height=2,width=20)

otsikko=tkinter.Label(ikkuna,text="Enter amount and press OK")
otsikko.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=5,padx=10)

painike_2=tkinter.Button(ikkuna,text="OK",command=tallennatiedot,height=5,width=20)
painike_2.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=10,padx=10)
painike_2.config(height=2,width=20)

painike_3=tkinter.Button(ikkuna,text="Stop",command=lopeta,height=5,width=20)
painike_3.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10,padx=10)
painike_3.config(height=2,width=20)


syote=tkinter.Entry(ikkuna,width=20)
syote.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=10,padx=5)

ikkuna.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Just a question; I'm not only using banana or carrot but many other classes like around 70, so how do I adjust the if and else part or any other part that should be amended? I'm thinking that the class that's detected is probably stored in the variable 'detections'.

Comment: You need to add a list for the classes, and then handle that in the code. The modified code can be found directly here: https://github.com/mih-ai/tukimateriaalia/blob/353d2b94858ac2335cbd419c63ccc21bc9f44ef0/banaani4.py